# validate select tag html php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to validate my select tag so that if the user has not selected a session an alert will appear when the submit button is pressed. I have my html and php code below, thanks

```
<select name="ses">

                <option> Select a Session </option>
                <?php

                $get_sess = "select * from sessions where course_id='1'";
                $run_sess = mysqli_query($con, $get_sess);

                while ($sess_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_sess)){

                $ses_id=$sess_row['session_id'];
                $ses_title=$sess_row['session_title'];

                echo "<option value='$ses_id'>$ses_title</option>";
                } ?>
</select>
```

my php code is:

```
<?php
//if submit button is set i.e 'publish exercise now' pressed then:
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $exercises_ses = $_POST['ses'];
    $exercise_text = $_POST['exercise_text'];

        if($_POST['ses'] == 'NULL'){
            echo "<script>alert('Please select a session for the exercise')</script>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @chris85 The session id shouldn't intentionally be 0 however it is being passed to the database as zero when a session isn't selected, any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. This will check that the value isn't "empty", check the manual for everything that qualifies as "empty", per comments I think this meets your criteria.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $exercises_ses = $_POST['ses'];
    $exercise_text = $_POST['exercise_text'];
    if(empty($_POST['ses'])){
        echo "<script>alert('Please select a session for the exercise')</script>";
    } else {
        // execute functions form value is correct
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see how this should work although  if a session is not selected the else is being executed and the session_id is still being passed as 0 to the database. Confused

Comment: Run `print_r($_POST)`. What do you get?

Comment: Array ([exercise_title]) => [ses] => Select a Session [exercise_text] => [submit1] => [type] => ie)

Comment: So it equals  `Select a Session`, not `0`. Make that option not selectable, `<option disabled> Select a Session </option>`.

Comment: Also are you inputting the user input direct to your DB?

Comment: @Davidaj success, no success?

Comment: This makes 'Select a Session' disabled but just replaces it with one of the sessions from the query i.e. session 1, session 2 etc

Comment: Do you want to allow `Select a Session` to be selectable? If so then try `<option value="0"> Select a Session </option>`.

Comment: didnt want  select a  session selectable, this worked, thank you !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90254/discussion-between-davidaj-and-chris85).

Answer (score 2):

`'NULL'` is a string, if you want to compare to null value - use `NULL`. 
I don't think that `$ses_id` in your db has value `'NULL'`.
Checking if value is set can be done with `isset`, and with `empty` for not empty:

```
if (isset($_POST['ses']) && !empty($_POST['ses'])) {
```

Comment: `!empty` with `isset` is redundant. If it isn't empty it is set. Only possible issue with `empty` is if OP has `0` as an id but OP has gone silent..